# How to design REST APIs for multiple views in LOB applications

Tags: api, rest

I'm currently struggling with our service design. We build LOB applications with many CRUD operations. We used ASP.NET Web API first to get going.

One of the problems we encounter is that we have many different views consuming our API. Every view has different requirements. For example a view requires...

- a "family" entity from our service
- a "family" entity with embedded family members
- a "family" entity with a subset of fields only
- a different representation of our entity

We decided to use OData to fix this but soon we encountered more problems with it:

- Microsoft discountinued the development on WCF Data Services, so we had to use the OData implementation of WebAPI. Unlike WCF Data Services you have to implement every basic CRUD action yourself with WebAPI controllers (we build a base class for this to keep it DRY)
- The implementation in WebAPI (OData v4) lacks a lot of features from the OData v4 spec like updating sub ressources, chaining operations like $expand($top). We created issues on GitHub for that but there isn't much progress on those.

I don't really get how other companies do this. For me "standard REST services" like described in many blog posts and tutorials are too basic for almost every LOB application I build so far. The only solution that might work is to send HTTP requests for each sub resource:

- GET /api/families/5
- GET /api/families/5/tags
- GET /api/families/5/members
- GET /api/families/5/address
- GET /api/families/5/contact

But this sounds like a huge scalability issue for me.

Some companies are working on this issue: Facebook introduced it's own query language and framework (GraphQL/Relay), Netflix is working on FALCOR.

How does this problem get solved nowadays? Not everyone is using OData I guess.

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't query strings work ?

`GET /api/families/5
GET /api/families/5?view=withMembers
GET /api/families/5?view=view2
...etc`